# Limiting user interaction with the workbook - hide workbook / show only userform

Tags: vba, hide, userform

Is it possible to get the same effect using `ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False` but only for one Workbook. I mean, I'd like to limiting user interaction only to UserForm, but I need have an access to anothers workbooks. At the moment this function cause hide workbook, but after open some another excel file - all object from userform are not available.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False
Starter.Show modeless
End Sub
```

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Please, create a form, let us say "Starter", having (at least) a button ("btExit"), copy the next code in its code module and show it. If the form in discussion already has some code in `Initialize` and `Terminate` events, please add the next code lines, too:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btExit_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
End Sub
```

So, you can simple use workbook `Open` event in this way:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Starter.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Comment: @Pawel U: Didn't you find some time to test the above solution? If tested, didn't it work as you need?

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is not working as I expected. I have office 365 and when I open workbook with code, I see 2 instance of Excel and still workbooks are visable. After open another excel file - my userform is gone and never back.
I am back to my previous solution, but this is not what I need:
`Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
Call Starter.Show(vbModeless)
End Sub `